# Hide specific TabItem in TabControl if not an admin

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, admin, tabcontrol

I am working with a TabControl in XAML,

however I only want certain TabItems to be available depending on the user.

`Admins = 1` therefore should have full access to the TabControl,

Non `admins = 0` therefore should only have specific tabs available.

How can I hide specific tabs depending on the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an MVVM architecture?

Comment: That is not a very secure way of handling authorization if that is the only thing stopping the users from doing admin-only things...

Comment: Also not real efficient.  Why build tab items that are not going to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, and I suppose which one you use depends on where the `IsAdmin` flag is stored

My personal preference is a `DataTrigger` which is based off a static `User` object which is set when the user first logs in

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding IsAdmin, Source={x:Static local:Settings.CurrentUser}}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

`Settings` would be a static class that contains a `CurrentUser` property that is set when the application starts up and the user logs in. `CurrentUser` has a boolean property called `IsAdmin`

Answer (score 1):

Create a value converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool myValue = (bool)value;

        if (myValue)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add this as a resource to your XAML:

```
 <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"></local:VisibilityConverter>
```

Assume that your property that shows if a user is admin named IsAdmin

```
<TabItem Visibility={Binding Path=IsAdmin, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
```

I think that is all.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide all tabs once the application loads and then do something simple like the following to show each tab depending on the users access level:

```
if (userId == 1) {
  foreach (var item in tabControl.Items) {
    item.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

} else if (userId == 0) {
   tabControl.Items[TableControlYouWantVisibile].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```